# Cannot Delete Last Contact - What Http Status Code?

Tags: rest, http-status-codes, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently building a Web API and have a specific scenario that I cannot determine which HTTP Status Code would be most appropriate to return.

**The Scenario**

I have a "client" resource which owns a collection of contact resources.

The invariant is that a client must always have at least one contact. Therefore, if a request is made to delete a contact and this contact is the last remaining contact for the given client, I need to return an appropriate HTTP response indicating that the request cannot be fulfilled as you "Cannot Delete the last contact".

My feeling is this should fall under the category of "4xx Client Error's"

I've considered the following Status Codes:

**400 Bad Request** - I've ruled this out as it's specifically regarding malformed request's in which the server is unable to understand.

**405 Method Not Allowed** - at first this seems suitable, but I think 405 indicates that this method should never be allowed, however the above scenario is only transient. Thoughts?

**409 Conflict** - I've been leaning towards this, however the common example given for this code is generally a concurrency exception/edit conflict.

Does anyone have any guidance as to how I should respond in this scenario?

Comment: `409` get's my vote in this case, as it's a conflict the user can resolve. That the common example is something else does not matter to me, other examples like this one exist. `400` is right out indeed, but there is something to say for`405` if you use actual `DELETE` requests... If not, 409 I say, but if you do... I see your dilemma.

Comment: Yep, I am using the DELETE verb here, but I think 405 indicates that the Method should _never_ be allowed on the given resource.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key is to look at the expectations on the client and caches when a particular status code is used.

Here's some chunks of RFC2616 that are useful to look at:

> 10.4.1. 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.

This indicates that the request itself is completely wrong - either syntactically or by the protocol.  Your specific case is really an application protocol error so this may indeed be appropriate.

> 10.4.6. 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.

This is a transient status code.  If the `DELETE` refers specifically to the contact resources itself (e.g., `DELETE /contacts/D9DF5176-EEE4-4C70-8DA7-BA57B82027A8`) then this is probably the most appropriate status code.  However, if the `DELETE` is on a different resource or a resource with a query (e.g., `DELETE /contacts?index=12`), then I would not return a 405.  Then again, I usually steer clear of using `DELETE` with anything resembling a query.

> 10.4.10. 409 Conflict
>
> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict. Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be possible and is not required.

This seems like the most appropriate status at first look.  I would probably prefer a 400 in your case.  A 409 would clearly indicate that there is a conflict with the resource but there really isn't anything that the requestor can do that could change the outcome short of completely altering the resource (i.e., add a contact first).  Most of the 409 responses were optimistic concurrency failures such as trying to modify a resource that was modified since it was retrieved.  For example, look at the [concurrency failures returned by AtomServer built over Apache Adbera](http://atomserver.codehaus.org/docs/protocol_reference.html).

So with all of that.  I would probably use something like `400 Cannot Delete Last Contact` as the response line.  Remember that you are allowed to change the phrase associated with the status code.  This is a really good time to do such a thing.

Comment: Thanks for your input D.Shawley, the reason I'm hesitant to use 400 is because the definition specifically states "due to malformed syntax". You seem to be broadening this definition to include application protocol. Have you any references that support that interpretation?

Comment: You also say that Method Not Allowed is transient. In my case, each contact is it's own resource as well, so they each have there own Uri, so by your argument I could use this code. However, the definition for this status code doesn't really indicate that it is transient. I return this status for resources that can _never_ be deleted, i.e. the client resource itself.

Comment: Ok, after discussing with some colleagues we've decided to go with 405. I'm marking this as the correct answer because it was useful in helping us to decide. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @jflood.net - very little in HTTP is absolute (e.g., 410 Gone comes to mind).  A 405 states that the requested action cannot be applied to the specified resource at this very instance in time.  I believe that it is even valid to return a 405 from a `DELETE` and include `DELETE` in the list of allowed methods in the response.